# Pyspark: How to pivot data depends on different role?

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to pivot a Dataframe which looks like:

| user_id | type | value | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_id1 | email | abc@abc.com |  |
| user_id1 | phone |  | 12345 |
| user_id2 | email | def@def.com |  |
| user_id2 | phone |  | 67890 |

To this one:

| user_id | email | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_id1 | abc@abc.com | 12345 |
| user_id2 | def@def.com | 67890 |

Please help if there is a way to achieve this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **`coalesce`** to combine `value, number` columns into one and then **`Pivot`** the type column.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([('user_id1','email','abc@abc.com',''),('user_id1','phone','','12345')],['userid','type','value','number'])

#coalesce on two columns
df = df.withColumn("temp_value",when(col("value")=="",lit(None)).otherwise(col("value"))).\
  withColumn("temp_number",when(col("number")=="",lit(None)).otherwise(col("number")))

df = df.withColumn("value",coalesce(col("temp_value"),col("temp_number"))).\
  drop(*["number","temp_value","temp_number"])
df.groupBy("userid").pivot("type").agg(first(col("value"))).show(10,False)

#+--------+-----------+-----+
#|userid  |email      |phone|
#+--------+-----------+-----+
#|user_id1|abc@abc.com|12345|
#+--------+-----------+-----+
```

Comment: or simply do `when type = 'email' then value else number` before pivot